# on/off switch in smartclient

Tags: smartgwt, smartclient

I want to desing on/off switch in my project. I use Smartclient for javascript and html5, css.
Is there any way I can provide user with option to on and off. Like we have in website or mobile??
[image]

Answer (score 1):

well, you may vote my (pretty old) post on their forum http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/technical-q-a/32097-switchitem-for-smartclient-10

EDIT: with the new forum's format you can't vote my post, instead you may bump it.

A native implementation from SmartClient's team will be way better than our, which we're using in a ListGridField:

```
isc.defineClass("SwitchButton", "Canvas").addProperties({
    contentsOn: '<div class="switchButton animateToOn"><div class="switchButtonBckgr_ON">' + 'ON' + '</div><div class="switchButtonBckgr_OFF">' + 'OFF' + '</div><div class="switchButtonCircle"></div></div>',
    contentsOff: '<div class="switchButton animateToOff"><div class="switchButtonBckgr_ON">' + 'ON' + '</div><div class="switchButtonBckgr_OFF">' + 'OFF' + '</div><div class="switchButtonCircle"></div></div>',
    contentsDefaultTrue: '<div class="switchButton defTrue"><div class="switchButtonBckgr_ON">' + 'ON' + '</div><div class="switchButtonBckgr_OFF">' + 'OFF' + '</div><div class="switchButtonCircle"></div></div>',
    contentsDefaultFalse: '<div class="switchButton defFalse"><div class="switchButtonBckgr_ON">' + 'ON' + '</div><div class="switchButtonBckgr_OFF">' + 'OFF' + '</div><div class="switchButtonCircle"></div></div>',
    contents: '<div class="switchButton defFalse"><div class="switchButtonBckgr_ON">' + 'ON' + '</div><div class="switchButtonBckgr_OFF">' + 'OFF' + '</div><div class="switchButtonCircle"></div></div>',
    click: function () {
        if (this.contents.contains("animateToOn")) {
            this.setContents(this.contentsOff);
        } else if (this.contents.contains("animateToOff")) {        
            this.setContents(this.contentsOn);
        } else {
            this.setContents(this.contentsOff);
        }
    }
});
```

usage:

```
isc.SwitchButton.create({ID: "switchButton"});
```

then in a boolean ListGridField:

```
{
     name: "BOOLEAN_FIELD", type: "boolean", width: 69, canEdit: false,
     formatCellValue: function (value, record, rowNum, colNum, grid) {
         if (value === true) {
             value = null;
             return switchButton.contentsOn;
         } else if (value === false) {
             value = null;
             return switchButton.contentsOff;
         }
         if (value == null) {
             if (value) {
                 return switchButton.contentsDefaultTrue;
             } else {
                 return switchButton.contentsDefaultFalse;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

css (beware: I don't guarantee about cross browser compatibility):

```
.switchButton {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    min-width: 67px;
    /*min-width: 77px;*/
    max-width: 120px;
    /*max-width: 130px;*/
    border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1px;
    height: 27px;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
}

.switchButton:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    border-radius: 14px;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 500;
}

.switchButtonBckgr_ON {
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 14px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
    font: bold 16px/ 28px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    z-index: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #218FEC;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#218fec), color-stop(.6, #218fec), to(#6eafe6));
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 9px 0 4px #007fea;
}

.switchButtonBckgr_OFF {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 14px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43);
    font: bold 16px/ 28px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    z-index: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 9px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.switchButtonCircle {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(.15, #d3d3d3), to(#fefefe));
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px white, inset 0 -1px 2px white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 14px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d3d3d3 15%, #fefefe 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px white, inset 0 -1px 2px white;
    z-index: 750;
}

div.defTrue div.switchButtonCircle {
    left: 40px;
}

div.defTrue div.switchButtonBckgr_ON {
    left: -10px;
}

div.defTrue div.switchButtonBckgr_OFF {
    left: 50px;
}

div.defFalse div.switchButtonCircle {
    left: 0px;
}

div.defFalse div.switchButtonBckgr_ON {
    left: -60px;
}

div.defFalse div.switchButtonBckgr_OFF {
    left: 10px;
}

div.switchButton.animateToOn {
    border-radius: 14px;
}

div.animateToOn div.switchButtonCircle {
    -webkit-animation: myAnimateToOnButton 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation: myAnimateToOnButton 0.2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    left: 40px;
}

div.animateToOn div.switchButtonBckgr_ON {
    -webkit-animation: myAnimateToOnSfondoOn 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation: myAnimateToOnSfondoOn 0.2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    left: -10px;
    /*-webkit-transform: translate(-10px);*/
}

div.animateToOn div.switchButtonBckgr_OFF {
    -webkit-animation: myAnimateToOnSfondoOff 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation: myAnimateToOnSfondoOff 0.2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    left: 50px;
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myAnimateToOnButton {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        left: 40px;
    }
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myAnimateToOnButton {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        left: 40px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnimateToOnSfondoOn {
    from {
        left: -60px;
    }
    to {
        left: -10px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnimateToOnSfondoOff {
    from {
        left: 10px;
    }
    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes myAnimateToOnButton {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        left: 40px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes myAnimateToOnSfondoOn {
    from {
        left: -60px;
    }
    to {
        left: -10px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes myAnimateToOnSfondoOff {
    from {
        left: 10px;
    }
    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}

div.animateToOff div.switchButtonCircle {
    -webkit-animation: myAnimateToOffButton 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation: myAnimateToOffButton 0.2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    left: 0px;
}

div.animateToOff div.switchButtonBckgr_ON {
    -webkit-animation: myAnimateToOffSfondoOn 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation: myAnimateToOffSfondoOn 0.2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    left: -60px;
}

div.animateToOff div.switchButtonBckgr_OFF {
    -webkit-animation: myAnimateToOffSfondoOff 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation: myAnimateToOffSfondoOff 0.2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    left: 10px;
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myAnimateToOffButton {
    from {
        left: 40px;
    }
    to {
        left: 0px;
    }
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myAnimateToOffButton {
    from {
        left: 40px;
    }
    to {
        left: 0px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnimateToOffSfondoOn {
    from {
        left: -10px;
    }
    to {
        left: -60px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnimateToOffSfondoOff {
    from {
        left: 50px;
    }
    to {
        left: 10px;
    }
}

/* Mozilla */
@-moz-keyframes myAnimateToOffButton {
    from {
        left: 40px;
    }
    to {
        left: 0px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes myAnimateToOffSfondoOn {
    from {
        left: -10px;
    }
    to {
        left: -60px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes myAnimateToOffSfondoOff {
    from {
        left: 50px;
    }
    to {
        left: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?? are you using checkBox??